# Format usb linux Western Digital external disks

Tags: usb, gparted, format, dd, fdisk

How can I format an external USB drive? 
I have a Western Digital external usb which adds automatically a virtual read-only CD partition which prevented me to run the standard ways to format a disk.

I read more than 3 threads here and I tried:

- Disks

  Output:

  ```
  Error creating file system: Command-line `parted --script "/dev/sdb" mktable msdos' exited with non-zero exit status 1: 
  Error: Input/output error during read on /dev/sdb
  Error: Input/output error during read on /dev/sdb
  Error: Input/output error during write on /dev/sdb
  Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdb: Input/output error
  (udisks-error-quark, 0)
  ```
- Gparted

  Output:

  ```
  Input/output error during read on /dev/sdb
  ```
- dd 
      sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb

  Output:

  ```
  dd: writing to ‘/dev/sdb’: Input/output error
  ```

After some hours searching I found [this tutorial](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/passport-vcd.html) which involves windows tools and it worked! I am happy about it but I would like to know a way to do the same only via Linux.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what the original problem is. You should mention that WD adds this secret VCD partition if that's what you were trying to remove. I only understood the issue after reading the linked article but most people won't bother. All necessary information should be in the question itself

Answer (score 4):

You want to try the `U3_tool` for linux: http://u3-tool.sourceforge.net.  Keep in mind it doesn't come with a guarantee, but it's worth a shot if you want linux only.  Alternatively you could run Wine.

Quote from that page:

### Overview

Tool for controlling USB flash devices that confirm to the U3 specifications. This program can control the following features:

- Replacing of CD image
- Changing of virtual CD allocated size and completely removing it
- Enabling and disabling Security
- Unlocking and changing password of secured U3 device
- Obtainig various device information

WARNING: This Software is still alpha. Since the commands for controlling U3 devices aren't publicly available, we don't excatly know what we are doing. Although the application has been tested on a Sandisk Cruzer micro and a Verbatim Store 'N Go, it is not said that it won't stop other devices from working. The author is not responsible for any damage to your device.

### Supported devices

In general all U3 USB flash devices should be supported.

A list of devices that are reported to work with this tool is available in the [forum](https://sourceforge.net/projects/u3-tool/forums/forum/746414/topic/3559573)

### Status

This program should be usable for day to day use. But beware that it is still under development.

### Installation

Download the latest release from the [Sourceforge project page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/u3-tool/files/), and follow the instructions provided in the package.

### Usage

#### Examples:

Removing U3 cd partition, making it a ordanarry UFD, under MS Windows where e:\ is one of the U3 device drives.

u3_tool.exe -p 0 E

Unlock secured data partition under Linux 2.6.20+

# ./u3_tool -u /dev/sg3

Replace /dev/sg3 with the scsi generic device associated with your device. The correct device can be deduced from the dmesg output.

Unlock secured data partition under Linux 2.4 using USB subsystem

# modprobe -r usb-storage
# ./u3_tool -u scan
# modprobe usb-storage

### Links

- [u3_tool sourceforge project page](http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/u3-tool)
- [U3 Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/u3)
- [McGrew Security's analysis of U3](http://www.mcgrewsecurity.com/research/hackingU3/)

Comment: I tried wine already the firmware updater doesnt recognise usb ports thx for the feedback will try your solution too

Comment: http://u3.sandisk.com/ does not exist anymore i tried to follow the install intructions I got some errors.  Thanks dor trying

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: with wine the firmware of the company couldnt find the usb 
with the u3 during installation procedure I had some compile errors when I tried to run the configure script.

Comment: /u3-tool-0.3 $ ./configure 
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: in `/home/dimitris/Downloads/u3-tool-0.3':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

Comment: try running `sudo ./configure` instead, and make sure that you can write to  `~/Downloads/`

Comment: Still there?  Did anything work?

Answer (score 0):

Here is **the way** (you must download [sg3_utils package](https://sg.danny.cz/sg/sg3_utils.html))

```
dev=$(sg_scan |grep "My Book"|cut -d' ' -f 1)
cfg=$(sg_raw -r 12 $dev 1a 00 20 00 0C 00 02 2>&1|cut -d " " -f 7-19)
disvcd="$(echo $cfg|cut -d " " -f 2-9) 00 $(echo $cfg|cut -d " " -f 11-13)"
echo $disvcd |xxd -r -p|sg_raw -s 12 $dev 15 11 00 00 0C 00 01
```